# How do you ask "is it ok if..."?

Tags: questions, formulation-idiomatique

How would you ask something along the lines of “Is it ok if…?” as in “Is it ok if I park here?” or “Is it ok if I bring my sister?”?

Google translate suggests either "*Est-ce que correct si…*" or simply “*Est-ce que je peux…*”. The first just seems wrong, and the second (“Can I…”) doesn't really have the same connotation in English, so I wonder if there's a better expression in French.

I've also considered “*Est-ce que d'accord si…*” or “*Est-ce que bien si…*”, but I'm not sure if either is correct usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First let's rule out *"<s>Est-ce que correct si...</s>"*, which is obviously... not correct. :)

**"Est-ce que je peux..."** is the natural way of asking, and the one I would usually use as a native speaker. The use of *"pouvoir"* really means we are asking for permission here.

> *Is it ok if I smoke here?*
>
> Est-ce que je peux fumer ici ?

As you said though, the meaning might be a bit different: you could argue it is a neutral way of asking. If you want to insist on your concern for others, you could use the verbs *"déranger"* or *"gêner"*.

> *Is it ok if I smoke here?*
>
> Est-ce que ça gêne si je fume ici ?
>
> Est-ce que ça dérange si je fume ici ?
>
> Est-ce que ça te dérange si je fume ici ?

If you are rather asking about rules you could use *"Est-ce qu'on a le droit de `+infinitif`"* or *"Est-ce qu'il est permis de `+infinitif`"*.

> *Is it ok if I smoke here?*
>
> Est-ce qu'on a le droit de fumer ici ?
>
> Est-ce qu'il est permis de fumer ici ? *(formal)*

*"<s>Est-ce que d'accord si...</s>"* is not correct, but you were close. You could ask *"Est-ce que c'est d'accord pour que `+subjonctif`"* or *"Est-ce que tu es d'accord pour que `+subjonctif`"*.

> *Is it ok if I go to the party tomorrow?*
>
> Est-ce que c'est d'accord pour que j'aille à la soirée demain ?
>
> Est-ce que tu es d'accord pour que j'aille à la soirée demain ?

Note that I used a different example as *"Est-ce que c'est d'accord pour que je fume?"* would sound strange, although not impossible: it would mean *"Is it cool if I smoke?"*.

You can also use *"Est-ce que ça pose problème si `+indicatif`"*, which comes neutral if it is about smoking, but much more subtle for more sensitive topics.

> *Is it ok if my ex comes?*
>
> Est-ce que ça pose problème si mon ex vient ?

At last, rangzen gave an example literally translating into *"Est-ce que c'est ok si..."*, which works, but note that it is extremely casual, much more than the English counterpart.

Comment: perfect answer it help me very much i do have the same query. :)

Comment: It is also possible to use the verb "pouvoir". We can also say : "Puis-je fumer ici ?". It is rather an equivalent of the English "May I ... ?", you are asking for permission.

Comment: A more oral way could be "Ca va si je ... ?". Also note that the sentence "It's ok" would be translated to "Ca va"  in french.

Answer (score 11):

It's always depend of the language level because "ok" is never used in "correct" or writing form.
Speaking with a friend for a party "Is it ok if I bring my sister ?" will probably be "J'emmène ma soeur, ok ?" (forcing) or "C'est ok si j’amène ma soeur ?" (asking) or "Est-ce que je peux emmener ma soeur ?" (mail/sms).
But to a stranger in front of a supermarket, you will use "Est-ce que je peux me garer ici ?" or more directly, in a hurry "Je peux me garer ici ?"

"Est-ce que correct si...", "Est-ce que d'accord si..." and "Est-ce que bien si..." are all wrong, it will probably be "Est-ce que c'est correct si...", "Est-ce que c'est d'accord si..." and "Est-ce que c'est bien si...".

Answer (score 8):

As a complement to rangzen answer, I would also use

> (Est-ce que) ça va si ... ?
>
> (Est-ce que) ça dérange si ... ?
>
> (Est-ce que) ça pose un problème si ... ?

Comment: at least describe you answer it will be helpful to newbies

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, *Est-ce que je peux...*  and *(Est-ce que) C'est bien si...* are two good ways to ask what you want to ask. In the question about parking you can say *Je peux garer ici?* or *Je peux me garer ici?*. The same goes with bringing your sister.

I wouldn't care too much about the nuance differences between the two languages. The French people know what you mean in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using “*Est-ce correct si…*”.

Comment: *Est-ce acceptable*, pourquoi pas, mais *est-ce correct*, ça ne me paraît pas être une formulation habituelle.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : je vous assure ;-)